# How to extract values out of a array using JSON Extractor in jmeter?

Tags: arrays, jmeter, json-extract

I want to extract below json and use values accordingly.

I/p JSON:-

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "message": "User created successfully",
  "id": [
    131188,
    131191
  ]
}
```

Here I want values of id field. I used JSON Extractor and gave expression as $.id which gives me [131188,131191] in a variable. Now I want to use individual values out of this array i.e. 131188 and 131191.
Any Idea how to do it?

Update : I don't want to use 2 JSON Extractors.

Comment: See this: https://www.testingexcellence.com/parse-json-response-using-jmeters-json-extractor/. This might help.

Comment: Use '$.id[0'] for 131188 and '$.id[1]' for 131191. This site is pretty handy http://jsonpathfinder.com/

Comment: For this i have to use 2 jsonextracter which i m trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [*] to your JSON path expression as below

```
$.id[*]
```

This will create a jmeter variable for each value.Note that you should use `-1` in the match numbers field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a json extractor and a "JSR223 PostProcessor" with groovy language. An example:

```
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   //String jsonString = vars.get("jsonFromExtractor")

   String jsonString = '''
   {
     "status": "Success",
     "message": "User created successfully",
     "id": [
       131188,
       131191
     ]
   }
   '''
   log.info("jsonString:" + jsonString)

   def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( jsonString )

   String idValue1 = json.get("id").get(0)
   String idValue2 = json.get("id").get(1)
   log.info("idValue1:" + idValue1)
   log.info("idValue2:" + idValue2)
```

I hope this helps